# How to create an assignment problem cost matrix

Tags: python

I have 250 projects and 50 supervisors. Each of our 130 students rank their preferred choice of projects from 1-5 (1 being favourite) and don't score the other 245. I would like to assign each student to a supervisor but a supervisor can only have up to 12 students.

I'm trying to make some dummy data but struggling to make the cost matrix.

Defining a matrix with random integers of size (5 x 5).

```
import random

def createMatrix(n):
    firstRow = random.sample(range(n),n)
    permutes = random.sample(range(n),n)
    return list(firstRow[i:]+firstRow[:i] for i in permutes)


N = 5
m = createMatrix(N)
for i in m:
    print(i)

[1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
[3, 4, 2, 1, 0]
[4, 2, 1, 0, 3]
[2, 1, 0, 3, 4]
[0, 3, 4, 2, 1]
```

But this is a Latin square matrix and I would like to allow some rows to contain duplicate values representing that two students have ranked a given same project the same value. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 130 `students` and want some duplicated choices. So generate f.e. 110 choices (already minor chance of a duplicate - but with 5 out of 250 not much).
Then choose some of the generated choices as dupe-candidates and and add some of them again until you got back up to 130 choices:

```
from random import sample,shuffle

projects = 250
students = 130
dup_choices = 20   # means we generate 110 choices and at least 20 will be dupes
per_dup = 5        # add up to this amount of dupes for each dupe candidate

un_duped = students - dup_choices 

# random samples
student_choices = [ sample(range(projects), k = 5) for _ in range(un_duped)]
# select dupe candidates
dups = sample(student_choices, k = max(0, dup_choices // per_dup) + 1)

# add enough of each duplicate to statisfy your numbers
for d in dups:
    student_choices.extend( (d.copy() for _ in range(per_dup) ) )

# integer rounding + 1 => you will overshoot - so trim back to number of students
student_choices = student_choices[:students]

# mix the dupes into the data
# shuffle(student_choices)
```

This will generate 130 choices of wich at least 20 are some kind of duplicate of some other.

You create your cost matrix from this data - the position of the projects number inside the students choice is its priority (0 == 1st, 1 = 2nd, ...):

```
costs = [[0 if pr not in choice else choice.index(pr) + 1 
            for pr in range(projects)]
         for choice in student_choices]



# print first 3 of choices / costs
for sc in student_choices[:3]:
  print(sc)

for c in costs[:3]:
    print (c)
```

Output:

```
[124, 174, 43, 181, 63]

[158, 110, 129, 120, 149]

[226, 238, 183, 249, 90]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
```

Comment: Ohh interesting, thank you very much! I think there's a small caveat. The student_choices matrix isn't quite the cost matrix though, right? I would imagine it is a 250 x 130 matrix where (rows are students and projects are students) and for each student there is a value 1 to 5 corresponding to 5 projects they like where the rest of the row are 0s (projects they don't like). What do you think?

Comment: @HCAI see edit - each ROW is one student, each COLUMN is one project. You can transpose it yourself if you want it the other way round - I did not quite get your _(rows are students and projects are students)_

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! The last bit I think is a typo.